# php is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: php, html, windows, variables, installation

So this is my path I have:

C:\Users\Ashesh.k\Desktop\php-5.5.12

I have Tried this:

Right click your My Computer, then Properties, Advanced System Settings, Environment Variables and then find PATH variable, add your PHP installation dir there. Close your previously launched CMDs, re-launch it, it should work now.

But Failed

Comment: can you post your entire PATH? Did you prepend it with a `;`?

Comment: @Ortix92 <DELETED FROM HERE BECAUSE IT EXCEEDED LIMIT>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\Program Files\Zero Install;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;D:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Rational AppScan\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor\bin;C:\Users\Ashesh.k\desktop\php-5.5.12

Comment: you are telling me that you have installed php on your desktop? Do you by any chance have 2 separate hard drives where your profile is stored on the other one?

Comment: @Ortix92 No,I have only 1 drive

Answer (score -1):

If you change the %path%, you have to reboot. Temporary you can solve it in a concrete console window like

> set path=c:\path\to\php\root;%path%

then you should be able to use php right in that particular console

> php -v

This issue isn't relevant for say Apache or IIS configs where you give a full path anyway.